# ADF MODEL exception to page jsf

Tags: exception, jsf, model, oracle-adf

is it possible (and if so how) to route the MODEL exception messages to be presented on the JSF page and NOT in a popup?

scenario:
JSF page contains master-detail tables
when a user clicks on a row of the master table, there are some operations (Iterator+ExceuteWithParams) executed in the detailImpl.java (by prepareRowSetForQuery(ViewRowSetImpl vrs).
some of those operations can return exceptions from the DB. we don't want those exception messages to be presented as popups, but instead to be shown inside the JSF page in a certain place that will be used for those messages (Ex. af:outputText). the component needs to be updated with the new error every time it was thrown from the model

how it can be done?
examples please

Answer (score 0):

try experimenting with 'af:messages' component.